# Pegar id de dois elementos html?

Tags: laravel

Eu tenho um array de inputs e uso pra gravar no banco

```
/*ANSWERS */
foreach($params['questionnaire_questions_answers'] as $key => $item){
    $student_anamineses_answers = DB::table('student_anamineses_answers')->insert(
        array(
            'student_anamnese_id' => $id,
            'questionnaire_question_id' => 2,/*VER COMO GRAVAR O questionnaire_question_id DINAMICAMENTE */
            'answer' => $item
        )
    );
}
/*ANSWERS */
```

O problema é questionnaire_question_id está em outro input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="questionnaire_question_id[]" value="'+ item.id +'" />\
<textarea required name="questionnaire_questions_answers[]" cols="80" 
   placeholder="Digite a resposta aqui" rows="3" id="perguntas"></textarea>')
```

É um sistema de perguntas e respostas. Eu gravo a pergunta tabela chamada question e depois preciso gravar as respostas na tabelas answers. Eu faço um foreach pra pegar o id do textarea questionnaire_questions_answers e assim poder gravar a resposta na tabela answers. Só que eu preciso pegar o id do questionario, q eu passo no input questionnaire_question_id. Quando eu faço um foreach nos textareas eu consigo pegar os dados (answers) e gravar no bano, mas não sei como fazer pra pegar o id do questionario e gravar na mesma tabela answers.
Como percorrer esse input e gravar as informações em questionnaire_question_id?

Comment: Eu não entendi bem, o problema, esse input ele é enviado junto dos outros dados ? consegue explicar o processo que está acontecendo, a pergunta está um pouco vaga.

Comment: Também não entendi muito bem o que deseja, você deseja aceder o `questionnaire_question_id` que está associado com a  `questionnaire_questions_answers`? Se assim for quando percorrer um  guarde o `index` e use no array do outro elemento. Penso que deseja fazer isto `questionnaire_questions_answers[0]` `questionnaire_question_id[0]`

Comment: editei a pergunta pra ver se facilita o entendimento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como os dois ids são variáveis distintas você tem que saber qual é a posição que deseja aceder.
Pode usar o `foreach` mas terá de criar previamente uma variável para armazenar a posição actual para depois conseguir relacionar com o outro array. Exemplo:

```
/*ANSWERS */
$acc = 0;
$outros_ids = $params['questionnaire_question_id'];
foreach($params['questionnaire_questions_answers'] as $key => $item){
    $student_anamineses_answers = DB::table('student_anamineses_answers')->insert(
        array(
            'student_anamnese_id' => $id,
            'questionnaire_question_id' => $outros_ids[$acc++],/*VER COMO GRAVAR O questionnaire_question_id DINAMICAMENTE */
            'answer' => $item
        )
    );
}
/*ANSWERS */
```

Outra solução poderia ser a utilização da função `array_shift` que remove o primeiro valor de um array e retorna-o.

```
/*ANSWERS */
$outros_ids = $params['questionnaire_question_id'];
foreach($params['questionnaire_questions_answers'] as $key => $item){
    $student_anamineses_answers = DB::table('student_anamineses_answers')->insert(
        array(
            'student_anamnese_id' => $id,
            'questionnaire_question_id' => array_shift($outros_ids),/*VER COMO GRAVAR O questionnaire_question_id DINAMICAMENTE */
            'answer' => $item
        )
    );
}
/*ANSWERS */
```

Pelo que percebi da sua pergunta é isto o que pretende fazer, corrija-me se tiver errado.